# My ant signjar task seems to be changing my password

Tags: ant, jar-signing, jarsigner

When I try to sign a jar with this line:

```
jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert_comodo.pfx MyJar.jar "le-01234567-0123-0123-0123-0123456789ab"
```

it prompts me for my password, and everything works fine.  When I try to sign it with this ant target:

```
<target name="sign_jars" depends="obfuscated_jar">
    <signjar 
            keystore="cert_comodo.pfx"
            alias="le-01234567-0123-0123-0123-0123456789ab"
            storepass="A, pa$$." <Not my real password or alias, btw>
            storetype="pkcs12">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="." includes="*.jar" />
        </path>
    </signjar>
</target>
```

I get this error:

```
[signjar] jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: failed t
o decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final blo
ck not properly padded
```

Which is the same error I get if I mistype my password.

Are the `$` characters in my password being modified by Ant somehow?  Is there a way I can trick ant into letting me type my password interactively?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to `ant` seeing `$$` as an escaped single `$`, thus passing the actual password string as `A, pa$` to jarsigner. If the problem is still relevant, try changing the password to `A, pa$$$$` for 2 `$`s to be escaped.

Some additional documentation from [Apache Ant™ Task Design Guidelines](https://ant.apache.org/ant_task_guidelines.html):

> ...  Ant 1.5 passes the single dollar sign "$" through in strings; Ant 1.4 and before would strip it. To get this fix in we first had to write the test suite to expose current behaviour, then change something so that single "$" was passed through, but double "$$" got mapped to "$" for backwards compatibility.